# "from pylab import *" returns NoneType object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm posting this because I'm having a problem with matplotlib in Python 3.7.0

I post here a copy of the error code I get:

```
    >>> from pylab import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1353, in <module>
    fontManager = json_load(_fmcache)
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 888, in json_load
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Salvador\\.matplotlib\\fontlist-v300.json'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 245, in <module>
    from matplotlib import cbook, mlab, pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 18, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1363, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 1344, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 978, in __init__
    ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "C:\Users\Salvador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 264, in findSystemFonts
    fontfiles.update(win32InstalledFonts(fontext=fontext))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I added more spaces where I think were needed to improve block readability.

So, I'll list what I already know:

- The program is an implementation of the Cahn-Hilliard equation (I omit the rest of the code because I don't think it's relevant in this context).
- The program ran well in another computer where I installed it in the exact same way only using 64-bit instead of 32 (I had to switch to this machine because they were moving them at the institute).
- I thought it could be the IDE, I was using PyCharm so I switched to IDLE. It didn't work.
- I thought of reinstalling matplotlib, tried it 4 times with no success (The error appeared with the 3.0.0 version and I even tried switching back to the 2.2.3, but still no success).
- I uninstalled Python-64bit and installed it again. It didn't work. I also tried with 32bit without luck (I did erase all folders containing the word "python" including the PyCharm installation and restarted my PC).

So basically, I'm at a loss since I don't know enough about Python or compilers of computer architecture to do anything more. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately a bug in the latest 3.0.0 realease of matplotlib, see e.g. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12173 Your option is to revert to matplotlib 2.2.3 until the bugfix is released in matplotlib 3.0.1 or to install the development version, where the bug is fixed by now.

Comment: Now that I checked "matplotlib.__version__" returns '3.0.0', which is very odd since I installed matplotlib deliberately from the 2.2.3 ".whl" file at PyPI (I did think that could be a problem and so I tried changing the version). How can I revert to the 2.2.3 version? Do I need to get it from another source or ensure it's not a .whl file?

Comment: Mhh, that is strange. Can you link to the exact file you downloaded? In any case if you do `python -m pip install matplotlib==2.2.3` you should really get the specified version. Can you test this?

Comment: Sure! I used https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/2.2.3/#files and chose "matplotlib-2.2.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl ". I'll try the command you sent.

Comment: Thank you very much. I ran the command you sent, installed the 2.2.3 version and the program worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

you can just use '!pip install matplotlib' to update it

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. The problem presented itself with the newest version, and as was stated in the post and comments by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it's a bug in the latest current version (3.0.0) which was actually solved by downgrading the software to the previous version (2.2.3)